# More efficiently compute transitive closures of each dependents while incrementally building the directed graph

Tags: graph-theory, dataflow, directed-graph, transitive-dependency, transitive-closure

I need to answer the question: **given a node in a dependency graph, group its dependents by their own transitive dependents which would be impacted by a particular start node.**

In other words, given a node in a dependency graph, find the set of sets of direct dependents which transitively have common dependents that derive from that particular starting node.

e.g. given the pseudo code:

```js
let a = 1
let b = 2
let c = a + b
let d = a + b
let e = a
let f = a + e
let g = c + d
```

You could compute this graph:

[image: Graph diagram]

If we used `a` as the start node we can see that of the dependents of `a`, both `c` and `d` have a dependent of `g`. And `f` has a dependent of `e` and `a`.

Notice that `a` has no impact on `b` at all, so it should not be taken into account when deciding how to group the dependents of `a`.

Using `a` as the start node, we'd want to get this grouped sets of dependents:

```
groups = {{c, d}, {e, f}}
```

`c` and `d` have direct or transitive downstream relations, and `e` and `f` together as well. But, for example, `e` and `f` have no dependent (downstream) relation at all with `c` or `d` either directly or indirectly (transitively). And `b` doesn't derive from `a` directly or indirectly, so it should not have any impact on deciding our grouping.

Also keep in mind that this graph is small for simplicity. It could be that transitive dependents happen much further down the subgraph than this example happens to have.

---

I did a bunch of paper research and indeed there are numerous solutions, however they don't have the performance characteristics I'm looking for. The graph is incrementally created over time, and at each stage I need to be able to answer this question so traversing the entire graph each time is a dealbreaker.

I think I have a major advantage that isn't referenced in the various approaches I could find: I have full control over the creation of the graph and the dependents are added in reverse topological order, so the graph is correctly sorted. With that in mind, I considered the obvious solution of computing the answer incrementally (dynamic programming).

I figured a bitmask would be a fast way to store and look up what dependents a given node has. When a dependent is added to a node, I would update that node's mask to include the bits of that dependent (which itself includes its dependents and so on)

```js
let maskCounter = 0;

class Node {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.dependents = [];
    this.mask = 1 << maskCounter;
    maskCounter++;
  }

  addDependent(dependent) {
    // Now our mask contains the bits representing all of
    // its direct and transitive dependents
    this.mask = this.mask | dependent.mask;

    // Need to see if this dependent has a transitive
    // dependent of its own that exists in one of the groups
    for (const group of this.dependents) {
      const result = group.mask & dependent.mask;

      if (result) {
        group.mask |= dependent.mask;
        group.values.push(dependent);
        return;
      }
    }

    // If reached, this dependent has no transitive dependents
    // of its own with any of this node's other dependents.
    // That's confusing, huh?
    this.dependents.push({
      mask: dependent.mask,
      values: [dependent]
    });
  }
}
```

The dependents would, however, need to be added in reverse order up the graph so that the graph sorted correctly and the top of the graph contains the masks of all its dependents.

```js
const a = new Node('a');
const b = new Node('b');
const c = new Node('c');
const d = new Node('d');
const e = new Node('e');
const f = new Node('f');
const g = new Node('g');

b.addDependent(c);
b.addDependent(d);
c.addDependent(g);
d.addDependent(g);
e.addDependent(f);
a.addDependent(c);
a.addDependent(d);
a.addDependent(e);
a.addDependent(f);
```

The bitmasks would incrementally look like this:

```
b = b 00000010 | c 00000100
b = b 00000110 | d 00001000
c = c 00000100 | g 01000000
d = d 00001000 | g 01000000
e = e 00010000 | f 00100000
a = a 00000001 | c 01000100
a = a 01000101 | d 01001000
a = a 01001101 | e 00110000
a = a 01111101 | f 00100000
===========================
a = 01111101
```

At the end `a` has a mask of `01111101`, each bit represents each of its downstream transitive dependents. Notice that the second to last bit is not flipped, that's the bit for `b` which does not depend on `a` at all.

If we look at the resulting value of `a.dependents` we see:

```
[
  { values: [c, d], mask: 0b00110000 },
  { values: [e, f], mask: 0b01001100 }
]
```

which provides the answer we're looking for, ultimately a set of sets. `a.dependents.map(group => group.values)`--this an array aka list but it's being used as a set for simplicity.

Here's a JSBin: https://jsbin.com/jexofip/edit?js,console

This works, and CPU-wise is acceptable because I'll very frequently need to know the grouped dependents but dependents change far less often.

The example above uses JavaScript for simplicity of demo, which uses 32-bit signed integers for bitwise operations so we can only create 31 unique nodes. We could use an arbitrary precision integer (e.g. [BigInt](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/bigint)) to create a "unlimited" number of nodes, but **the problem is memory usage.**

Because each node needs their own unique bit flipped, I *think* the memory usage is:

```
N * (N + 1) / 2 = bits      (where N = number of nodes)

e.g. 10,000 nodes is about 6.25 megabytes!
```

That's excluding any platform overhead for using arbitrary precision integers (or a similar custom data structure).

In my use case, it would be common to have 10k+ and in fact 100k+ is probable in some cases (625 MB !!!) and it's also possible for new nodes to be created indefinitely, using an infinite amount of memory, so this solution isn't practical because there is no easy way to "garbage collect" no longer used mask bits from nodes that drop off the graph--it's of course possible, but it's the traditional GC problem I'd like to avoid if possible.

Side note: depending on the size and depth of the graph, this might not actually perform well either. Even though bitwise operations themselves are relatively fast, doing it on on a BigInt of 100,000 bits for each node at the top of the graph is not. So completely rethinking my approach is also welcome.

---

Ultimately trading memory for CPU is the usual give and take, but I'm wondering if perhaps I'm missing another approach that strikes a better balance or requires significantly less memory?

There may be other unique considerations I haven't thought of that could be used.

School me!

Comment: This does not clearly define you want--output as a function of input.  It's not obvious from your example & "group its dependents by their own transitive dependents" is not clear.

Comment: @philipxy sorry about that. I edited it a bit to hopefully clarify. Given a node in a dependency graph, group its dependents by their own transitive dependents. E.g. here are the two groups in the example `[[b, c], [e, f]`. I've achieved that the with the example code using bitmasks, however my goal is to find an approach that doesn't use nearly as much memory and hopefully is similar (or better) in speed. Does that make sense?

Comment: @philipxy just realized I replied with the exact same phrase you mentioned isn't clear. I'm not sure how to reword, I'll give it some thought. Thanks!

Comment: You're not explaining "group". What value of what type is the output given a value of what type for the input? Apparently the input is characterizable as a set of nodes & a set of ordered node-node pairs (edges) but be clear about your choice. Any restrictions on the graph? Eg must it be connected? PS Please clarify via post edits, not comments. PS Specify & initially code using straightforward relevant data types--lists, sets, etc--not via some encoding in an type like a bitmask that is not natural for the problem. PS Please use text when possible--eg for your graph. PS Give a "code snippet"?

Comment: @philipxy thanks for taking the time! I've made more edits and done my best to elaborate, but admittedly it's a tough problem for me to explain clearly.

Comment: A few things jump to mind that might be worth considering. A) the bitmaps may be quite sparse, so might compress down significantly. De-compress on the fly. B) using a bloom-filter for a probabilistic approach - can test if there might be a mutual dependency before doing the full calculation

Comment: As currently written a Node will only be added to the *first* group for which it has a transitive dependency (because of the early return). For example, add another edge `e.addDependent(d)` and depending on statement ordering you can have groups `[[b, c, e], [f]]` or `[[b, c], [e, f]]`. Shouldn't the result be `[[b, c, e], [e, f]]` in this case?

Comment: @LaurenceRowe I may have explained it incorrectly. A node should only belong to a single group, together with all other dependents who have direct or transitive dependents between them. `e` has no downstream relation on `b` or `c`. It might help to think about this as a dataflow graph. Any propagation of change to `b` or `c` has a downstream impact on `d` but no impact on `e`. `d` is actually a direct dependent of them both, but it could just as well be much further down the graph but if the two subgraphs eventually intersect they are transitively related.

Comment: "the dependents are added in reverse topological order" and "Also, the graph can also contain cycles" don't make sense together. Topological order only make sense in a directed *acyclic* graph. We need a graph theoretically-consistent specification of this problem before we can know how to answer it.

Comment: How sparse or dense are you expecting this graph to be? How many nodes do you need to perform this dependency grouping on, and how frequently, relative to graph updates? Do you know the nodes of interest in advance?

Comment: @user2357112 I've removed the requirement of supporting cycles. The graph will vary in density without any notable patterns. The grouping needs to be known after every graph change and the graph can change at any location, potentially with multiple additions and/or deletions for a single graph update, so traversing the entire graph each time is undesirable. Not sure what you're asking in your last question. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hi. You use a lot of words yet are still unclear, because you don't use clearly defined terms precisely. You seem to mean, given a node & a dependency graph that it is in, partition its children per the set that holds a given child & its dependents. (We would normally expect "is a dependent of" to be the transitive closure of "is a child of".) All that is further required is then a representation for input & output--which clarifies "partition" & "dependency graph" in the context of asking for an algorithm. (See my first comment.)

Comment: PS Examples of lack of clarity: "which would be impacted by a particular start node" is unclear. But why add it? A node gives you its children, then you partition them per the nodes reachable inclusively from a given one. You don't clarify or consistently use "dependant"--you use it as "child" & "descendant" but also use "immediate dependent" for "child" & it's not clear whether "transitive" dependent includes children. You misuse "transitive closure of"--it's a relation that is a function of a given relation, not the set of nodes in that or such a set minus a given node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the 'reachable' nodes for each node as a bitmask and doing a bitwise AND certainly sounds hard to beat computationally. If the main issue with this is the high memory usage then perhaps this could be seen as a memory compression issue.

If the bitmasks are very sparse (lots of zeros) there is a chance they will compress down to a much smaller size.

I image you'll want to find a compression library that could de-compress the bitmasks as a stream. That way you could do the bitwise AND as it decompresses - allowing you to avoid storing the fully decompresses bitmask.

Comment: I originally wanted to avoid compression because I naively thought that it would be slower (decompression usually is) but I discovered Roaring Bitmaps https://roaringbitmap.org/ and did some profiling and discover it is in fact _faster_ in many cases where I have an extremely large graph. Presumably because a very large BigInt requires more memory alloc and checking the intersection between two of them has to check every bit and they're often very sparse, whereas Roaring Bitmaps doesn't (complex implementation, I recommend reading about it). Very cool! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The relation you want to group by is not an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation). For example, consider this dependency graph:

[image: a->bcd, bc->e, cd->f]

Here, **b** and **c** have a common dependent, and so do **c** and **d**, but there are no common dependent between **b** and **d**. In this case, you probably want to have **b**, **c** and **d** in the same group. However, it gets trickier with this case:

[image: a->bd, bc->e, cd->f]

Here, **a** doesn't depend on **c**, so you may want to have **b** and **d** in separate groups, now that you don't need to care about **c**. However, there is a class of algorithms which will group **b** and **d** together in this case: algorithms which maintain grouping of *all* nodes, and use this as a basis for grouping new node's direct descendants.

One such algorithm uses a [disjoint-set structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) to efficiently track which nodes are connected. In my example, before processing **a**, the algorithm will have nodes **b**, **c**, **d**, **e**, and **f** all in the same set, so they will be grouped together.

Here is an implementation:

```js
function find(node) {
  return node.parent == null ? node : (node.parent = find(node.parent));
}

function merge(a, b) {
  a = find(a);
  b = find(b);
  if (a.rank < b.rank) {
    a.parent = b;
  } else {
    b.parent = a;
    if (a.rank == b.rank) {
      ++a.rank;
    }
  }
}

class Node {
  constructor(name, dependents) {
    this.name = name;
    this.parent = null;
    this.rank = 0;
    let depMap = new Map();
    for (let d of dependents) {
      let dset = find(d);
      if (!depMap.has(dset)) {
        depMap.set(dset, []);
      }
      depMap.get(dset).push(d);
    }
    output += name + ': ' + Array.from(depMap.values()).map(a => '{' + a.join(', ') + '}').join(', ') + '\n';
    for (let d of depMap.keys()) {
    // or: for (let d of dependents) {
      merge(this, d);
    }
  }

  toString() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

let output = '';
const f = new Node('f', []);
const e = new Node('e', [f]);
const d = new Node('d', []);
const c = new Node('c', [d]);
const b = new Node('b', [d]);
const a = new Node('a', [b, c, e, f]);
document.getElementById('output').textContent = output;
```

```html
<pre id=output></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! I want to clarify a few things to make sure we're on the same page: In the first example, my code would produce `[[b, c, d]]` all grouped together, which is correct for my use case. In the second example my code would produce: `[[b], [d]]` which is also correct because a change to `a` has no impact on `c` and so `b` and `d` have no transitive relation in regards to `a`--they do have a transitive relation in general via `c` as you mention, but that relation isn't applicable in this use case.

Comment: I think that's a very interesting point that I failed to note in my question, that it's not just any transitive relation, it's only those which would be impacted by `a`. Not sure of the term for that. So with this in mind, can you clarify your comment "This, however, means that algorithms that maintain grouping of all vertices processed so far won't work"?

Comment: @jayphelps I edited my answer to make it more clear. My algorithm doesn't always produce the exact result that you need (sometimes it puts nodes in the same group when they should be in different groups), but it is much more efficient than your bitmask-based algorithm, so this may be an acceptable trade-off.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks again! Unfortunately I believe it is not an acceptable tradeoff for my use case.

Comment: Super glad you brought up the point about unrelated subgraphs, I modified my example to include that.

Comment: The result partitions the children of a parent, so children are certainly being grouped per an equivalence relation, with the groups the equivalence classes, although the asker's description wasn't/isn't clear. See my most recent comment on the question re that relation.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a directed acyclic graph, you can perform [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of the nodes, and that seems like a good basis for subsequent steps. Toposorting itself can be done efficiently. There are implementations in FRP-inspired libraries such as my [crosslink](https://github.com/monfera/crosslink) or paldepind's [flyd](https://github.com/paldepind/flyd)

Also, check out [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7231/efficient-algorithm-for-retrieving-the-transitive-closure-of-a-directed-acyclic).

Comment: Thanks for the link! I may be misreading but it looks like the linked answer is effectively what I’m doing already, is it not? I’m not sorting because the graph is being built up incrementally already in correct topological order.

Comment: ... looks like this referred approach can handle circularities too http://www.cs.hut.fi/~enu/thesis.html, based on Tarjan's algorithm for strong component detection https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm

Comment: @jayphelps I'm not sure, take a look at the time and space complexity in the above link with Tarján's; of course O(whatever) doesn't make constant factors unimportant